# How to package an Android Library for Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, packaging, android-library

I'm maybe missing something but I do not get it. How and where can you publish your libs (done with Android Studio as a module) in order that the people just have to write (for example)

```
compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.5.2'
```

in their `build.gradle`?

I saw things like jCenter repositories but I've no experience with packaging and found it very confusing.

Thanks for help! :)

**EDIT**

Of course, I want to publish a github project under Apache :)

Comment: See [this](http://zserge.com/blog/gradle-maven-publish.html) and [this](http://www.vandalsoftware.com/post/52468430435/publishing-an-android-library-aar-to-a-maven) and [this](https://www.virag.si/2015/01/publishing-gradle-android-library-to-jcenter/).

Comment: Ok, that's what I wrote, just wanted to see if it was the good direction. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

https://jitpack.io/ is also a good choice if you just want to publish an android library on github.

There is a [example](https://github.com/CodeFalling/RecyclerViewSwipeDismiss)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try when I'll do another lib because I already released using the old fashion way :)

Comment: I have done everything also created the tag with the release , but when I try to import com.github.myName:myRepo:1.0.0 not find it .. can you tell me why? @falling

Comment: @MicheleLacorte You can check its status at https://jitpack.io/#myName/myRepo at first.