# how to add my github library on android studio

Tags: android, android-library, jcenter

I have a library such as LibraryOne and it's package name is com.gorkem.libraryone and i pushed library to github. When i use this library on other project, i want to access this library with dependecies like that: compile 'com.gorkem.libraryone' how they do that ? i can give many example such as compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'. Are there any tutorials for this issiue ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to package an Android Library for Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578889/how-to-package-an-android-library-for-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to publish your library in JCenter or Maven.

Just follow this tutorial: https://www.virag.si/2015/01/publishing-gradle-android-library-to-jcenter/

Answer (score 1):

https://jitpack.io must be what you want,use this and you can use

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gorkem.libraryone:v1.0.0'
}
```

You can refer to [this project](https://github.com/CodeFalling/RecyclerViewSwipeDismiss) as example